# Google Apps Script Templated HTML

Tags: google-apps-script

Has   "Google Apps Script templates" been deprecated.  When the showSidebar code is run below  it displays the following in the sidebar:

```
Hello, World! The time is .
```

==========================

## File: code.gs

```
function showSidebar() {
   var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
  .setTitle('test');

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

======================

## File: index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello, World! The time is <?= new Date() ?>.
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the link to google  documentation on apps script templates

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

Comment: You say you want to use an `HtmlTemplate`, yet you make an `HtmlOutput` directly...

Answer (score 3):

No, templates have not been Deprecated.

Rather than use `createHtmlOutputFromFile()`, you must use `createHtmlTemplateFromFile()`, then evaluate the template with `evaluate()` to generate your HtmlOutput.

This process is shown in at the top of the documentation you linked.